# web.config custom 404 page returning blank file

Tags: iis, http-error

I have this web.config in the directory /websites/.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
      <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">  
            <clear/>
           <error statusCode="404" path="/__web-errors/404.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />                
           </httpErrors>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <remove name="wordpress" />
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

There is also this file in /websites/__web-errors/404.html

```
<h1>404 - Page not found</h1>
```

However, it shows a blank page. Is there a reason for this and how do I stop it?

Comment: Do you run the app on a IIS?

Comment: Please, look this video guide, probably it will be helpful http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CRcVuH_G7Lk

Comment: Have you tried `/__web-errors/404.html` in the browser, does that work? If IIS has a problem showing that page it displays a blank page instead,

Comment: @PeterHahndorf Yes i have, it exists.